# Building and migrating to software raid 5 array

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, raid, raid5

I am hoping to build and migrate to a software raid 5 array. I am working with ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS 64-bit. I currently have three drives:

- /dev/sda1 which is a 60G solid state drive which contains my root directory and serves as my boot drive;
- /dev/sdb2 which is a 1.5T standard hard drive that mounts in my home directory and acts as my main storage and also contains swap space;
- /dev/sdc1 which is a 1.5T standard hard drive that mounts in media which I have been using for back up.

Now that /dev/sdb2 is full I am reconsidering my data management approach. I am considering buying another 1.5T drive and using it with the other two to form a single RAID 5 array hopefully mounted in my home directory. I would like to migrate to the array without destroying the data currently held on /dev/sdb2.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: The minimum number of disks for RAID 5 is 3 disks, to migrate to this raid, I believe you will need to move your data to another location before you can drop it onto your raid array. As far as I know in-place transition is not supported

Comment: Yeah you will need to empty the hard drive before making it part of a RAID array.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. OK, lets say that I bought two additional drives. The goal would be then become:

1) Create a three disc raid

2) Migrate data 

3) Add original drive to the array